# Is there a subsystem of ZFC which constrains the Universe to $L$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals, constructive-mathematics

The Axiom of Constructibility states that $V$, the Universe of all sets, is equal to $L$, the Constructible Universe.  When added to $ZFC$ does not place a constraint on what sets exist, instead what it says is that if $ZFC$ says that a particular set exists, then it occurs somewhere in the constructible hierarchy.

But my question is, is there a set theory weaker than $ZFC$ which (intuitively) only posits the existence of a set if it can be proven to exist in $L$?   I’m not sure how to formulate such a set theory.  Maybe restricting the comprehension axiom to subsets of a set $X$ which are elements of $Def(X)$?

Comment: Sounds like KP, or something like that.

Comment: I don't understand the question - how would *weakening* ZFC yield a theory which has *more* constraints?

Comment: @NoahSchweber The title doesn’t quite capture what I want to ask, I just didn’t know a better way to phrase it in a short title.  The body captures it though - intuitively, I only want to posit the existence of a set if we know it to be an element of $L$.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well, since ZFC is compatible with V=L, doesn't ZFC already do that?

Comment: @NoahSchweber No, it doesn’t do what I want.  There are plenty of sets which $ZFC$ proves the existence of which in the absence of the axiom of constructibility we do not know to be an element of $L$.  I want a theory which only proves the existence of a given set if (intuitively) in the absence of the axiom of constructibility we know the set is an element of $L$.  Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @NoahSchweber At the very least I want a theory $T$ such that for all sets $x$, if $ZFC$ does not prove that $x\in L$, then $T$ should not prove the existence of $x$.  But I don’t want the theory to actually talk about what $ZFC$ does or does not prove.  In the end of my question I mentioned restricting comprehension as one way to achieve what I want.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I see what you're getting at now, but there are some issues making it precise. Talking about a theory proving the existence of a set is inherently problematic, since you're mixing theories and structures. You can talk about proving the existence of a set satisfying a given formula, but then you wind up with annoying trivialities. For example, consider the formula "If V=L then $x=0$, otherwise $x$ is non-constructible." Any theory proves that there is an $x$ satisfying this formula, but ZFC can't prove that such an $x$ must be constructible. Etc.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well, you can talk about formulas that define what elements a set contains.  We can say that if $ZFC$ does not prove that $\{x:\phi(x)\}\in L$ then $T$ should not prove that $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ exists.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That doesn't behave well: consider the example in my previous comment.

Comment: Well, your example wasn’t about a formula defining the elements of a set.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But it's easily modified to be such. E.g. the set of $x$ such that either $x=0$ and $V=L$ or $x$ is a minimal-rank non-constructible set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the notion of a set which a theory proves exists is inherently problematic, and it's difficult to formulate a version of the requirement "All sets which we can prove exist, can be proved to be in $L$" which doesn't fail for silly reasons.

It seems to me, though, that the following is probably the strongest theory which will match the intuitions behind such a requirement:

- First, we take the usual axioms of ZFC and relativize them to $L$. So, for example, Powerset becomes "For every constructible $x$ there is a constructible $y$ such that for every constructible $z$, if every constructible element of $z$ is in $x$ then $z$ is in $y$, and every constructible element of a constructible element of $y$ is in $x$."
- Now the resulting theory $ZFC^L$ is fine: any model of it has a definable subset which is a model of ZFC+V=L. However, by relativizing *everything* we've made stuff a bit weird. For example, the *rest* of such a model could be truly awful, and the "$L$-part" itself might not sit nicely in the whole (e.g. it might not be transitive). So we probably want to pass to a stronger theory $ZFC^L_+$, consisting of $ZFC^+$ together with unrelativized Extensionality, Union, Pairing, and Foundation, and an axiom asserting that the ordinals of $L$ are exactly the ordinals of the universe.
- The result is a theory all of whose models satisfy a very weak set theory, but which have an inner model satisfying ZFC+V=L. And this seems as close to what you want as I can think of.

Comment: So how does comprehension work, any formula $\phi$ is OK as long as we relativize quantifiers to $L$? In any case, this sort of thing isn’t what I had in mind when I asked the question, though it does satisfy the requirement I specified. What I wanted to do is a make a theory that doesn’t treat $L$ as some completed totality that you refer to, but instead builds $L$ up one level at a time, defining sets in later levels of the constructible hierarchy in terms of sets in lower levels of the constructible hierarchy, in the same way that $ZFC$ builds up the cumulative hierarchy.  Is that possible?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But ZFC *doesn't* build up the cumulative hierarchy; the cumulative hierarchy is defined **after the fact**. The ZFC axioms themselves just reference "the universe," and in that sense treat $V$ as a completed entity right from the start.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I mean, ZFC just allows you to take the power set of any given set, and then in retrospect we have the cumulative hierarchy.  I’d like to do the same thing.  I want an axiom asserting that given any set $X$, all the elements of $Def(X)$ are sets, and an axiom asserting that $Def(X)$ itself is a set, and then in retrospect we have the constructible hierarchy.